# Cloud function to find and delete deleted user id in every sub-collection

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-functions

> Q. What's the best practice to find and remove a deleted user id from different sub-collections `friends` under each user id in `users collection`?

---

#### Assumption

This is an example data structure.

```
- users [collection]
    - user A [document]
        - friends [sub-collection]
            - cqeDIDZhOtf7DmGX42XPs6jwjX22 [document]
    - user B
        - friends
            - cqeDIDZhOtf7DmGX42XPs6jwjX22
```

> User `cqeDIDZhOtf7DmGX42XPs6jwjX22` has removed from the cloud function below.

```
exports.deleteUser = functions.auth
  .user()
  .onDelete(event => {

    // perform desired operations ...
});
```

---

> Q. What's the most efficient way to write a cloud function which finds a match with the following user id `cqeDIDZhOtf7DmGX42XPs6jwjX22` in `friends sub-collection` and **removes** from the Firestore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to iterate all your user documents, then delete the document in each `friends` subcollection with the id of the user that was deleted.  There's no way to have a single query span multiple collections - you're going to have to reach into them all individually.

Comment: Thank you for the response Doug. Do you think that's normal for my use case? I'm a bit concerned about the performance issue.

Comment: If you want to make this easier, you should consider restructuring your data to better support how you're going to access it.  This is always the recommended approach for nosql databases.

Comment: Well, is it also ok to denormalize the data like I used to do in rt database? I'm trying to avoid duplicating user data.

Comment: Yes, denormalization is very common for nosql type databases.

Comment: Thank you, Doug. I should think about restructuring my data again.